# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass Creating a Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary, undefined

I'm trying to create a registration for students to be able to register for the sections that are available to them. However, I keep getting this error when i actually hit the create registration button. When i check the live shell it says that @student == nil meaning it's not being created properly? I'm confused as to how I could fix this though

```
<!---REGISTRATION CONTROLLER-->

def new
    @registration = Registration.new
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @info = Section.for_rank(@student.rank).for_age(@student.age).map{|s| ["Name: #{Event.find_by_id(s.event.id).name}, 
        Ranks: #{ s.max_rank == nil ? "#{Student::RANKS[s.min_rank-1][0]} and up" : "#{Student::RANKS[s.min_rank-1][0]} - #{Student::RANKS[s.max_rank-1][0]}"},
        Ages: #{ s.max_age == nil ? "#{s.min_age} and up" : "#{s.min_age} - #{s.max_age}" }", s.id] }
end


def create
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
    if @registration.save
        redirect_to @registration, :notice => "Successful"
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end

<!----MY REGISTRATION FORM -->

<div class="field">
<%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => @registration.student_id %>
```

```
<div class = "field">
<%= f.select :section_id, options_for_select(@info)%>
```

```
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-mini'  %></th>
```

```
<!--- MY STUDENT SHOW THAT CALLS THE REGISTRATION -->

<%= link_to 'Register ', new_registration_path(:student_id => @student.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini'  %>
```

Comment: Can you post your `for_age` method? The error is suggesting that you're calling `map` on `nil`, which (based on the code you've posted) is only called on the result of `for_age`. I think the results you're getting in the shell are misleading, your parameters might be different there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the answer to your particular question is, but there is a problem with this method - it's defining presentation in the controller, which is not the controller's responsibility.

Whatever you're trying to do in the `map` block, it's a huge mess. If something goes wrong in there, and I can all but guarantee that it eventually will, it will be unnecessarily difficult to debug. It looks complicated enough that you should probably make a few presenter classes to handle the select options generation, so all you would need to do is something like this:

```
SectionSelectOptions.new(@student).to_options
```

The `SectionSelectOptions` class might be something like this:

```
class SectionSelectOptions
  attr_reader :student

  def initialize(student)
    raise ArgumentError unless student
    @student = student
  end

  def to_options
    sections.map {|section| SectionOption.new(section, student).to_option }
  end

  private

  def sections
    Section.for_rank(student.rank).for_age(student.age)
  end

end
```

And the `SectionOption` class:

```
class SectionOption
  attr_reader :section, :student
  def initialize(section, student)
    @section = section
    @student = student
  end

  def to_option
    ["#{name}, #{ranks}, #{ages}", section.id]
  end

  private

  def name
    "Name: #{section.event.name}"
  end

  def ranks
    "..." # I'll let you refactor whatever is going on here
  end

  def ages
    "..."
  end
end
```

Granted, it's longer than the single line of code that's creating the issue for you, but this has several advantages:

1. It splits every step into it's own method, so when you're interface changes, you have one place to change it (e.g., it the lookup for sections changes, you just change the `sections` method)
2. It's testable, either through the public interface or through individual methods
3. It's easier to debug. You'll now know exactly what's going on when something goes wrong, because your errors will tell you which method to look at.